# WPF TreeView Binding to a complex model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, treeview

I've started to learn about WPF. And I've chosen to build simple ItemStructureCreator.
I am using MVVM pattern as well.
I implemented some classes, and faced an problem to properly bind it to my TreeView.

[image: Here is my class diag]

Now I want my StructureManagerView to have TreeView control assosiated with my structure.
I tried to bind it like this:

```
    <TreeView Name="tree" DataContext="{Binding MainItem}" Grid.Column="0" Background="Beige">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Item.Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Code}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate> 
    </TreeView>
```

Or like this (Here I think is wrong cause `ItemsSource` property expects collection):

```
    <TreeView Name="tree" ItemsSource="{Binding MainItem}" Grid.Column="0" Background="Beige">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Item.Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Code}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate> 
    </TreeView>
```

Can you please help me to set `Bindigs` correctly.

Regards, Dmitry.

Comment: The TreeView doesn't have the concept of a "Main Item". You should Bind the ItemsSource Property of the TreeView Itself. I Mean, your `ItemsSource="{Binding MainItem}"` should be replaced by `ItemsSource="{Binding MainItems}" where MainItems is an IEnumerable.

Comment: TY for your response. Yes I tried it right now and it showed me main item. But my HierarhicalDataTemplate didn`t work properly. It didnt show items. Now i see that I need datatemplate for ItemMaterialViewModel. But what it must be? A Style, a DataTemplate or what?

Comment: Change `ItemsSource="{Binding Item.Children}"` to just `ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"`

Comment: That's not working)
now each `TreeViewItem` Binded to `ItemMaterialViewModel`, that contains `Item` of `ItemViewModel`. And that item has a Children.

Comment: Post the code for your classes.

Comment: I solved this question. There was some mistake when I buld my tree sample. PS: post your 1st comment into the answer. I'll mark it as resolved. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting My comment into an answer:

The TreeView doesn't have the concept of a "Main Item".

You should Bind the ItemsSource Property of the TreeView Itself.

`ItemsSource="{Binding MainItem}"`

should be replaced by

`ItemsSource="{Binding MainItems}"`

where MainItems is an IEnumerable